# Taking from eventChannel

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I get an error when I `take` from `eventChannel`.
The websocket is connected successfully. Im able to receive message outside of the eventChannel using `onmessage` callback.  `redux-saga@0.5*`

```
function createSocketChannel (socket){
  return eventChannel(emit => {
    socket.onmessage = msg => emit(msg);
    return () => socket.close();
  }, buffers.sliding(10));
```

}

```
const channel = yield call(createSocketChannel, socket)
const payload = take(channel) //error: not valid channel or         not valid pattern
```

Comment: Good question.  Event channel looks correct to me.  `take` looks good except your not `yield`ing in front of your `take`.  Typo in this question?  Have you tried removing buffer to see if the event channel works without it?  Have you logged what `channel` looks like before you try to `take` it?

Comment: Try debugging createSocketChannel before you `call` it. You might be importing it wrongly.

Comment: @tpdietz i did `yield take` first which did not work before taking it off.

Comment: @kadlec i use following import from the redux-saga docs eventChannel example. `import { eventChannel, END } from 'redux-saga'`

Comment: @tpdietz `buffers` has also been taking off. I dont really know what it should look like but console gives me `{@@redux-saga/IO:true, CALL: { context:null, fn: f args:Array(1)}}`. From @kadlec thoughts, import maynt be right. In the source codes... `take(arg)` expects `arg` to have a `take` or `close` function which is not present in the log.